# ClearCase: Find elements containing one of several attributes

Tags: clearcase

On ClearCase I use the following command to find all the elements that have the `foo` attribute with the value `"yes"`:

```
cleartool find . -ver 'foo == "yes"' -print
```

Is there a way to retrieve in a single command the elements that have the `foo` attribute with the value either `"yes"` **or** `"maybe"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `||` operator should be supported here:

```
cleartool find . -ver 'foo == "yes" || foo="maybe"' -print
# or
cleartool find . -ver {'foo == "yes" || foo="maybe"'} -print
# or
cleartool find . -ver \{'foo == "yes" || foo="maybe"'\} -print
```

See this [more elaborate example](http://www.samecs.com/commands/cleartool%20commands/find/find.htm#_Toc193967932) for instance:

> with one attribute and state but not a second attribute and state, and then create the second attribute and state

```
cleartool find . -version \{CIstate=="Approved"  && !PRCR_controlled=="ClearQuest_Controlled" && version(/main/LATEST)}\ ' -exec \'cleartool mkattr PRCR_controlled \"ClearQuest_Controlled\" \”$CLEARCASE_XPN\”\'
```

The section "[logical operator](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21124425#logical-operators)" details how they are used:

> The `cleartool find` command can be used with the QUERY LANGUAGE to take advantage of logical operators.
>   Review the IBM Rational ClearCase Information Center on the topic of query_language ([`cleartool man query_language`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/query_language.htm)) for more details.
>
> Example:
>
> Use the `cleartool find` command with the logical not (`!`) `&` and (`&&`) operators to find all versions for an element that are not labeled with either of two label types in the VOB.

```
cleartool find . -version !"lbtype(tested) && !lbtype(release) " -print
```